# Where to learn about the Google Maps API in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I am trying to learn a lot more about the Google Maps API in Android.  I have been doing some online tutorials and playing around with MapView and the Overlay classes, but I haven't really been very successful in gaining a good understanding of the setup.

I went to my local Barnes & Noble and checked the Android development guides they had available, but they all either just mentioned the Google Maps API in passing or spent the entire chapter explaining how to get the key and set it up, and left the rest up to the reader.

The internet has also not been very helpful, and looking through StackOverflow has only made me more frustrated as every solution seems to be pulled out of thin air, or some repository of API knowledge in the sky.

I was wondering if anyone who is experienced and knowledgeable on this subject could help me in my quest for knowledge, or if anyone who is not could give me some advice as to what other resources are available other than the reference, which is never a good place to go to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[http://www.amazon.com/Pro-Android-3-Satya-Komatineni/dp/1430232226/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1325362142&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430232226)

Chapters 17 and 25.

Answer (score 3):

I am finding best website for learning TUT 
you also Like this.

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

If any Query then please tell me.

Comment: This is one of the ones I checked out, but it didn't help me understand anything, it just got me set up with sample code and then left me hanging.

Comment: Something that explains how to work with Google Maps in an Android environment in a comprehensive enough fashion that I can feel confident improvising my own path instead of making modifications within the frame of code that someone else has written.

Answer (score 0):

Select the Option from here: [this link](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html)

So from there you can get the different option of the maps api for android.
Also find in code.google.com project that are very good information to understand the APi and their use. . .

Also see [this link](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/google-maps-on-android-android.html) and [this link](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/location-manager-android-developer.html).

It will realy help you a lot.
Enjoy. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for something more advanced and comprehensive than this.

Comment: Which type of understanding or knowledge you want ? regarding functionality of the Map or basic information of it or what else ??

Comment: I want to be able to imagine something in Google Maps and then implement it through improvisation and creativity.  Those links just set me up with a map viewer and leave me hanging.

Comment: ok. Google API gives many thing like diretion, Distion, Place Co-ordinate, Place name, and Many other thing. You can see that in the Google Map API and google others api like as like google place Search Api where you can implement the different technology in your application. try it if you want like that.

Comment: I'm more thinking about like how to add things to the map and interact with it.